# ¿Se puede acceder a todo el historial de tareas en la plataforma Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Jenkins y me gustaría saber si se puede acceder a todo el historial de tareas, o por lo menos ir más allá de las 10 últimas builds.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar ejecutar un script en la consola de scripts que esta en Manage Jenkins y después Script Console.

```
def NumerosH = 24
def FechaFrmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss")
def NombreBuild = 30

def Tempo = System.currentTimeMillis() - NumerosH * 3600 * 1000


SortedMap TM = new TreeMap();
for (job in Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(BuildableItem.class)) {
  for (build in job.getBuilds()) {
    if (build.getTimeInMillis() < Tempo) {
      break;
    }
    TM.put(build.getTimeInMillis(), build)
  }
}

def formato = "%-10s%-${NombreBuild}s%-10s"

println(String.format(formato, "Estado", "Build", "Tempo"))
for (entry in TM.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
  def Bilder = entry.getValue()
  println(String.format(formato, Bilder.getResult(), Bilder.getFullDisplayName(), FechaFrmt.format(Bilder.getTime())))
}
```

Este es uno sacado de otra pregunta parecida, puedes probar a ver si te da resultado o si te da un concepto cercano a lo que buscas.

Answer (score 1):

Hola te dejo esta pequeña solución utilizando el API REST de Jenkins:

```
curl -X GET http://IP:8080/job/JOB_NAME/api/json?pretty=true --user USER:API_TOKEN
```

> IP: La IP donde esta corriendo Jenkins.
>
> JOB_NAME: El nombre del Job del que quieres obtener el historial de builds.
>
> USER: El usuario que utilizas de Jenkins.
>
> API_TOKEN: El token del usuario que estas utilizando, para más detalles de como generar el token puedes acceder a este enlace [click](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API).

La API te responderá con un JSON parecido al siguiente:
[[image: json_demo]]

La petición la puedes realizar desde jenkins con el comando de ejemplo o desde cualquier lenguaje de programación utilizando una petición REST.